# Dealing with ZeroOrMore in pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse pactl list with pyparsing: So far all parse is working correctly but I cannot make ZeroOrMore to work correctly.

I can find `foo:` or `foo: bar` and try to deal with that with `ZeroOrMore` but it doesn't work, I have to add special case `"Argument:"` to find results without value, but there're `Argument: foo` results (with value) so it will not work, and I expect any other property to exist without value.

With this definition, and a fixed pactl list output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#
# parsing pactl list
#

from pyparsing import *
import os
from subprocess import check_output
import sys

data = '''
Module #6
    Argument:
    Name: module-alsa-card
    Usage counter: 0
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "14.0-rebootstrapped"
'''

indentStack = [1]
stmt = Forward()

identifier = Word(alphanums+"-_.")

sect_def = Group(Group(identifier) + Suppress("#") + Group(Word(nums)))
inner_section = indentedBlock(stmt, indentStack)
section = (sect_def + inner_section)

value = Group(Group(Combine(OneOrMore(identifier|White(' ')))) + Suppress(":") + Group(Combine(ZeroOrMore(Word(alphanums+'-/=_".')|White(' ', max=1)))))
prop_name = Literal("Properties:")
prop_section = indentedBlock(stmt, indentStack)
prop_val = Group(Group(identifier) + Suppress("=")  + Group(Combine(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+'-"/.')|White(' \t')))))
prop = (prop_name + prop_section)

stmt << ( section | prop | ("Argument:") | value | prop_val )

syntax = OneOrMore(stmt)

parseTree = syntax.parseString(data)
parseTree.pprint()
```

This gets:

```
$ ./pactl.py

Module #6
    Argument:
    Name: module-alsa-card
    Usage counter: 0
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "14.0-rebootstrapped"
[[['Module'], ['6']],
 [['Argument:'],
  [[['Name'], ['module-alsa-card']]],
  [[['Usage counter'], ['0']]],
  ['Properties:',
   [[[['module.author'], ['"Lennart Poettering"']]],
    [[['module.description'], ['"ALSA Card"']]],
    [[['module.version'], ['"14.0-rebootstrapped"']]]]]]]
```

So far so good, but removing special case for `Argument:` it gets into error, as ZeroOrMore doesn't behave as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#
# parsing pactl list
#

from pyparsing import *
import os
from subprocess import check_output
import sys

data = '''
Module #6
    Argument:
    Name: module-alsa-card
    Usage counter: 0
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "14.0-rebootstrapped"
'''

indentStack = [1]
stmt = Forward()

identifier = Word(alphanums+"-_.")

sect_def = Group(Group(identifier) + Suppress("#") + Group(Word(nums)))
inner_section = indentedBlock(stmt, indentStack)
section = (sect_def + inner_section)

value = Group(Group(Combine(OneOrMore(identifier|White(' ')))) + Suppress(":") + Group(Combine(ZeroOrMore(Word(alphanums+'-/=_".')|White(' ', max=1))))).setDebug()
prop_name = Literal("Properties:")
prop_section = indentedBlock(stmt, indentStack)
prop_val = Group(Group(identifier) + Suppress("=")  + Group(Combine(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+'-"/.')|White(' \t')))))
prop = (prop_name + prop_section)

stmt << ( section | prop | value | prop_val )


syntax = OneOrMore(stmt)

parseTree = syntax.parseString(data)
parseTree.pprint()
```

This results in:

```
$ ./pactl.py

Module #6
    Argument:
    Name: module-alsa-card
    Usage counter: 0
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "14.0-rebootstrapped"
Match Group:({Group:(Combine:({{W:(ABCD...) | <SP>}}...)) Suppress:(":") Group:(Combine:([{W:(ABCD...) | <SP>}]...))}) at loc 19(3,9)
Matched Group:({Group:(Combine:({{W:(ABCD...) | <SP>}}...)) Suppress:(":") Group:(Combine:([{W:(ABCD...) | <SP>}]...))}) -> [[['Argument'], ['Name']]]
Match Group:({Group:(Combine:({{W:(ABCD...) | <SP>}}...)) Suppress:(":") Group:(Combine:([{W:(ABCD...) | <SP>}]...))}) at loc 1(2,1)
Exception raised:Expected ":", found '#'  (at char 8), (line:2, col:8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alberto/projects/node/pacmd_list_json/./pactl.py", line 55, in <module>
    parseTree = syntax.parseString(partial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1955, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 6336, in checkUnindent
    raise ParseException(s, l, "not an unindent")
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected {{Group:({Group:(W:(ABCD...)) Suppress:("#") Group:(W:(0123...))}) indented block} | {"Properties:" indented block} | Group:({Group:(Combine:({{W:(ABCD...) | <SP>}}...)) Suppress:(":") Group:(Combine:([{W:(ABCD...) | <SP>}]...))}) | Group:({Group:(W:(ABCD...)) Suppress:("=") Group:(Combine:({{W:(ABCD...) | <SP><TAB>}}...))})}, found ':'  (at char 41), (line:4, col:13)
```

See from `setDebug` `value` grammar `ZeroOrMore` is getting the tokens from next line `[[['Argument'], ['Name']]]`

I tried `LineEnd()` and other tricks but none works.

Any idea on how to deal with `ZeroOrMore` to stop on `LineEnd()` or without special cases?

NOTE: Real output can be retrieved using:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['LANG'] = 'C'
data = check_output(
    ['pactl', 'list'], universal_newlines=True, env=env)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indentedBlock` is not the easiest pyparsing element to work with. But there are a few things that you are doing that are getting in your way.

To debug this, I broke down some of your more complex expressions, use setName() to give them names, and then added .setDebug(). Like this:

```
identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums+"-_.").setName("identifier").setDebug()
```

This will tell pyparsing to output a message whenever this expression is about to be matched, if it matched successfully, or if not, the exception that was raised.

```
Match identifier at loc 1(2,1)
Matched identifier -> ['Module']
Match identifier at loc 15(3,5)
Matched identifier -> ['Argument']
Match identifier at loc 15(3,5)
Matched identifier -> ['Argument']
Match identifier at loc 23(3,13)
Exception raised:Expected identifier, found ':'  (at char 23), (line:3, col:13)
```

It looks like these expressions are messing up the indentedBlock matching, by processing whitespace that should be indentation space:

```
Combine(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+'-"/.')|White(' \t')))
```

The `"` character in the Word and the whitespace lead me to believe you are trying to match quoted strings. I replaced this expression with:

```
Combine(OneOrMore(Word(alphas, alphanums+'-/.') | quotedString))
```

You also need to take care not to read past the end of the line, or you'll also mess up the indentedBlock indentation tracking. I added this expression for a newline at the top:

```
NL = LineEnd()
```

and then used it as the `stopOn` argument to `OneOrMore` and `ZeroOrMore`:

```
prop_val_value = Combine(OneOrMore(Word(alphas, alphanums+'-/.') | quotedString(), stopOn=NL)).setName("prop_val_value")#.setDebug()
prop_val = Group(identifier + Suppress("=")  + Group(prop_val_value)).setName("prop_val")#.setDebug()
```

Here is the parser I ended up with:

```
indentStack = [1]
stmt = Forward()
NL = LineEnd()

identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums+"-_.").setName("identifier").setDebug()

sect_def = Group(Group(identifier) + Suppress("#") + Group(Word(nums))).setName("sect_def")#.setDebug()
inner_section = indentedBlock(stmt, indentStack)
section = (sect_def + inner_section)

#~ value = Group(Group(Combine(OneOrMore(identifier|White(' ')))) + Suppress(":") + Group(Combine(ZeroOrMore(Word(alphanums+'-/=_".')|White(' ', max=1))))).setDebug()
value_label = originalTextFor(OneOrMore(identifier)).setName("value_label")#.setDebug()
value = Group(value_label
              + Suppress(":")
              + Optional(~NL + Group(Combine(ZeroOrMore(Word(alphanums+'-/=_.') | quotedString(), stopOn=NL))))).setName("value")#.setDebug()
prop_name = Literal("Properties:")
prop_section = indentedBlock(stmt, indentStack)
#~ prop_val = Group(Group(identifier) + Suppress("=")  + Group(Combine(OneOrMore(Word(alphanums+'-"/.')|White(' \t')))))
prop_val_value = Combine(OneOrMore(Word(alphas, alphanums+'-/.') | quotedString(), stopOn=NL)).setName("prop_val_value")#.setDebug()
prop_val = Group(identifier + Suppress("=") + Group(prop_val_value)).setName("prop_val")#.setDebug()
prop = (prop_name + prop_section).setName("prop")#.setDebug()

stmt << ( section | prop | value | prop_val )
```

Which gives this:

```
[[['Module'], ['6']],
 [[['Argument']],
  [['Name', ['module-alsa-card']]],
  [['Usage counter', ['0']]],
  ['Properties:',
   [[['module.author', ['"Lennart Poettering"']]],
    [['module.description', ['"ALSA Card"']]],
    [['module.version', ['"14.0-rebootstrapped"']]]]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for that wonderful explanation. I'm sure all the tips will help in many other cases to use this powerful module!. Original gist updated: https://gist.github.com/zyga/5534776#gistcomment-3742655